# Thymeleaf - How to write th:text?

Tags: thymeleaf

How can add tag after th:text so that i use `br`  and `em`. Now here name is showing but after that the br tag and and em tag get skipped

Edited and removed the `)`

```
<span class="profile" th:text="${user.name}>
   <br>
   <em class="class_name" th:text="${user.subinfo}></em>
</span>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to change the structure of your HTML, you have two alternatives.

1. Use the `<th: block />` tag.

   ```
    <span class="profile">
      <th:block th:text="${user.name}" />
      <br>
      <em class="class_name" th:text="${user.subinfo}"></em>
    </span>
   ```
2. Use the `th:inline="text"` attribute.

   ```
    <span class="profile" th:inline="text">
      [[${user.name}]]
      <br>
      <em class="class_name" th:text="${user.subinfo}"></em>
    </span>
   ```

Comment: Thanks @Metroid so sorry for late reply

Answer (score 1):

Thymeleaf will replace everything inside your `<span>` tag with the contents of the Thymeleaf `th:text="${user.name}"` processor.

To work around this, you can wrap everything in an extra enclosing `<span>` and then populate the inner contents as follows:

```html
<span>
    <span class="profile" th:text="${user.name}"></span>
    <br>
    <em class="class_name" th:text="${user.subinfo}"></em>
</span>
```

This renders the following HTML:

```html
<span>
    <span class="profile">John Smith</span>
    <br>
    <em class="class_name">some more info</em>
</span>
```

Comment: Thankyou i know this way but by addidng another covering span it just distorts my css. Is there any other workaround

Comment: Understood - You may want to update the question to clarify the problem. You can use `th:utext` to concatenate string literals containing HTML to your `${...}` values - but that will be messy and harder to understand for people looking at the code. Also, I strongly prefer to avoid `th:utext` as it opens the door to injection attacks. It may be better to adjust the CSS.

Answer (score 0):

As per the code you've paste. The issue is that you haven't closed the  tag properly.

```
   <em class="class_name" th:text="${user.subinfo}">)</em>
```